# Postgresql stored procedure return table all columns

Tags: postgresql

A function is created. The function has a input parameter. I can return a column but I want to return all table columns. Also I want to do if result is zero the function return just 0. How can I do it?
Here the error result.

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>       HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>       CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.returnallcolumns(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
>       ********** Error **********
>       ERROR: query has no destination for result data
>       SQL state: 42601
>       Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>       Context: PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.returnallcolumns(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwgcould.returnallcolumns(IN sessionId character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF public.mytable AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM public.mytable WHERE session_id=returnallcolumns.sessionId ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: What is the error you get? But "*I want to return all table columns*" contradicts: "* the function return just 0*" you can't return "all columns" in one case and just one column in other cases.

Comment: İf no result returning value will be 0. İt is not possible?

Comment: It seems to do what you want. It is stable not volatile

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to return a result, you need to use `return query` in PL/pgSQL [**as documented in the manual**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwgcould.returnallcolumns(IN sessionId character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF public.mytable AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  return query --<< this was missing
    SELECT * 
    FROM public.mytable 
    WHERE session_id = returnallcolumns.sessionId 
    ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

But you don't need PL/pgSQL for this, a simple SQL function will be more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwgcould.returnallcolumns(IN sessionId character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF public.mytable AS
$BODY$
    SELECT * 
    FROM public.mytable 
    WHERE session_id = returnallcolumns.sessionId 
    ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This return a single column(that name is "mytable"). In that column all values added with comma. How to get result with all columns like tables?

Comment: @balron: did you use `select * from returnallcolumns(...)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No , finally i noticed that i need to query as select * from ... , thanks :)

Comment: How to get all data from a dynamic table which name pass as in parameter?

Answer (score 0):

How to get all data from dynamic table in the PostgreSQL database which name pass as in parameter?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS schemaName."GetAllDataFromDynamicTable";

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaName."GetAllDataFromDynamicTable"(IN P_DynamicTableName text)
    RETURNS SETOF schemaName."P_DynamicTableName" 
AS $$
BEGIN
  return query
    SELECT *
    FROM schemaName."P_DynamicTableName" -- this table name every time change
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```